# Run time and space complexity of this code

Tags: runtime, big-o, space-complexity

I'm having a bit of trouble determining the big o of this solution I came up with on a CTCI question
The space complexity should be O(1)
but is the run time O(N)? It seems to be more towards O(N^2) because of the while loop. But the while loop does not run N times for each element inside the for loop.

```
public static int[] missing_two(int [] n){

        for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++){
            while(n[i]!=i){
                int temp=n[i];
                n[i]=n[n[i]];
                n[temp]=temp;
            }
        }

    }
```

Would 6,0,1,2,3,4,5 be an example of worst case here?
The while loop will run n times on the first index. and 0 afterwards. Therefore shouldn't this be O(2n) => O(n)?

Comment: Are you sure that code works ? I may be parsing it wrong, but  if `n[i]==i` then  `n[i]==n[n[i]]` so your exit condition `n[i]!=i+1` gets you stuck on an infinite loop.

Comment: ahh thank you for pointing that out. You're right about that

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that big O notation is used for giving an upper bound limit or a worst case scenario. The question you have to make yourself is: Could input vector n have values such that at least in one case, for all values in input vector n, the while loop is fully executed? Then a correct Big O notation would be O(N^2), if not but close, then I guess O(N^2) would still be a better estimation than O(N), as O(N) for an upper bound would have already been exceeded.

Now that you have edited the question and given more info about it I agree with you. It is O(N)

Comment: Yes  it is possible, for example 6,0,1,2,3,4,5. However at the first index. it will do n cycles, but all the following index will be 0 cycles. so im thinking its more towards 2n.

Comment: If it is possible the assume that n vector has 10 samples, then for is called 10 times and for every time for is called the while is called another 10 times, doesn't that make it 100 instead of 20?

Comment: I believe at the worst case scenario. The while loop will only loop 10 times on one of the element. during those 10 loops. it is sorting the rest of the array. The condition for the while loop to trigger is n[i]!=i(I made a mistake on my code earlier) So after that first loop, the rest of the element will not trigger the while loop to occur. On the example I gave about. 6,0,1,2,3,4,5. On the first index, it will swap 6, with 5. then 5 with 4 etc. until it become 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. When it move on to the next index. n[1]=1, therefore it will not trigger the while loop.

Comment: Ok, I see you've edited your question. O(2n) => O(n) as you say. I agree with you

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.